# Google+ Platform for Android - NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.samples.plus.SignInActivity

Tags: android, google-plus, noclassdeffounderror

I want to run the google+ sample: PlusSampleActivity.

The steps to do this are defined here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

1. Download Google Play services to my eclipse;
2. In the Google APIs Console , create an API project
3. In the Services pane, enable the Google+ API

   - In the API Access pane, create an OAuth 2.0 client ID
   - set the name product
   - select android
   - set packagename as: com.google.android.gms.samples.plus
   - generate Signing certificate fingerprint using keytool
   - Create client ID
4. Import sample as describe on the page

The project does not have any compile time errors.

But if I run application, I get an exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) at
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409) at
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021) at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121) at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943) at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624) at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:   
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

I have no idea what is wrong, when I tried to run a simpler application of Step 3 Initialize the PlusClient, an analogous exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com.example.ExampleActivity...
```

Of course I added access to the application by adding new Client ID.

Reference is added to the library correctly

**I solved my problem:**

Right click the project, select Android Tools -> Add Support Library

[Source on how to do this.](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/tips-to-add-support-library.html)

Comment: Did you also include the google_play_services library, as explained in Step 2?
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#step_2_run_the_google_sample_app

Comment: Yes, problem solved: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/tips-to-add-support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

Try running **Project**->**Clean** to clear up the issue. This seemed to work for one person.

The library is referenced automatically by the project, but perhaps Eclipse is forgetting about this and needs to be reminded.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer, as user1861240 stated, is to:
**Right click your project, select Android Tools > Add Support Library...**

Apparently this sets the latest revision of the support library for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but Add Support Library didn't work for me. I also tried Project-> Clean and restart Eclipse. Eventually it worked after I changed the target API to 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow what is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)
Keep in mind to follow the project set up as well, and dont ignore any step.